# Python:requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))

Tags: python, python-requests

I encounter this error when I'm trying to download a lot of pages from a website. The script is pieced up and modified from several other scripts and it seems that I am rather unfamiliar with Python and programming.

The version of Python is 3.4.3 and the version of Requests is 2.7.0.

This is the script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os.path

s = requests.session()
login_data = {'dest': '/','user': '******', 'pass': '******'}
header_info={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0'}
url='http://www.oxfordreference.com/LOGIN'
s.post(url,data=login_data,headers=header_info)

for i in range(1,100):
    downprefix='http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/acref/9780198294818.001.0001/acref-9780198294818-e-'
    downurl=downprefix+str(i)
    r=s.get(downurl,headers=header_info,timeout=30)
    if r.status_code==200:
        soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
        shorten=str(soup.find_all("div", class_="entryContent"))
        fname='acref-9780198294818-e-'+str(i)+'.htm'
        newname=os.path.join('shorten',fname)
        htmfile=open(newname,'w',encoding="utf_8")
        htmfile.write(shorten)
        htmfile.close()
        print('Success in '+str(i))
else:
        print('Error in '+str(i))
        errorfile=open('errors.txt','a',encoding="utf_8")
        errorfile.write(str(i))
        errorfile.write('\n')
        errorfile.close()
```

The complete trackback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 372, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 374, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\http\client.py", line 1171, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\http\client.py", line 351, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\http\client.py", line 321, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: ''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 245, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 309, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 374, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\http\client.py", line 1171, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\http\client.py", line 351, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\http\client.py", line 321, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\stuff\Mdict\dict by me\odoa\newahktest\CrawlTest2.py", line 14, in <module>
    r=s.get(downurl,headers=header_info,timeout=30) 
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 477, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\python343\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
```

Answer (score 1):

The host you're talking to did not respond properly. This usually happens when you try to connect to an https service using http, but there may be a lot of other situations too.

Probably the best way to check what's going on is to get a network traffic analyser (for example [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)) and look the connection.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I look thoroughly into the request header in firefox's developer tool and find the cookie in the browser is different from the cookie I get after "r=s.get(downurl,headers=header_info,timeout=30)". Is there anything wrong?